# Iframe: White screen after setting document.location 2x

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm creating a web application that I aim to embed into my Wix site.

The web application that I need can basically be reduced into a text screen & a button to change the screen view/page (the html that is displayed).

However, the problem is that independent on whether I start from the "home page" or from the "page page", the application loads two next screens and gives me a white screen after.

I've also tried other options for changing the url - ie `location.href`, `window.location` and such, and even tried changing the page via `<a href= URL` , yet the problem persists.

Below is a simplification of my code:

**Page HTML**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    
    
      <head>
    <base target="_self">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
        </head>
      <body>
          <h1>page page</h1>
              <button id="pagebtn" class="font-family: Raleway; font-size: 16px; waves-effect waves-light btn-small  blue accent-2"><i class="material-icons left">check</i> Navigate to home </button>
    
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    
    <script> 
    
    document.getElementById("pagebtn").addEventListener("click",changepage);
    
    function changepage(){
    
    
      var url_new = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzKN9vYBa1yQguooTnijIipyMdAMbXo7a61wjWHt0ybCynH2bxj/exec?v=home"; 
      document.location = url_new;
    }
    
    
    </script> 
      </body>
    </html>
```

**Home HTML**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    
    
      <head>
        <base target="_self">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
      </head>
      
      
      <body>
          <h1>home page</h1>
              <button id="homebtn" class="font-family: Raleway; font-size: 16px; waves-effect waves-light btn-small  blue accent-2"><i class="material-icons left">check</i> Navigate to page </button>
    
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
    
    document.getElementById("homebtn").addEventListener("click",changepage);
    
    function changepage(){
    
    
      var url_new = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzKN9vYBa1yQguooTnijIipyMdAMbXo7a61wjWHt0ybCynH2bxj/exec?v=page"; 
      document.location = url_new;
    }
    
    
    </script> 
      </body>
    </html>
```

**JS Code // Code.gs**

```
var Route = {};

Route.path = function(route, callback) {
  Route[route] = callback;
}

function doGet(event) { //<!-- Not visible to the user, serverside --> 
  Route.path("page", loadPage);
  Route.path("home", loadHome);

  if (Route[event.parameters.v]) {
    return Route[event.parameters.v]();
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("home").evaluate();
  }
  
  Logger.log("do get1 " + event.parameters.v);
}

function loadPage() { //<!-- Not visible to the user, serverside --> 
  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page");
  return tmp.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function loadHome() { //<!-- Not visible to the user, serverside --> 
  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("home");
  return tmp.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
```

The links in the code are for redirecting to a different url "view".

Thanks!

//Edit:
Unfortunately still without a solution nor an understanding of the underlying cause of this problem. By simply testing around - I found that when using window.open the scripts works (however, it keeps opening new tabs/windows that is not desirable. As the URL of the site itself does not change - perhaps this is the underlying reason for this problem? (meaning that I should redo the router or input the url in a different way to actually change what is written)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by changing document.location to window.top.location

However, as I need to embed this inside of my website, it opens up a new window whenever (window.top after all), whenever clicking the "Navigate" buttons- it does not work as intended, but for a temporary fix it will do